# Using ngClass with ngRepeat

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an AngularJS partial view which contains the following nav:

```
<nav class="pull-right">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-class="{disabled: !button.isDisabled()}">
            <a href="{{here}}" ng-click="button.onClick()">{{button.text}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In the controller, I have defined an array of nav buttons, each of which has three properties:

- text -- the text to display in the button
- onClick() -- the action to take when the button is clicked
- isEnabled() -- whether the button is enabled or not

For each li in the ngRepeat, I want to add the (Bootstrap) css class .disabled if the current button.isEnabled() returns false.

The problem I'm having is if the last button in the ngRepeat is disabled, all of the buttons have .disabled class. If I move the ngClass directive to the anchor, nothing works right (I can provide details on how if necessary).

Comment: need to see how `isEnabled` works in controller. Is better if that can be a variable not function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is using `.isDisabled()` but your controller has `.isEnabled()`.

Comment: That was it exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `disabled` class does anything to links. It only works for buttons and inputs.  Instead of using disabled, I'd use `ng-if` to toggle the link:

```
    <li ng-repeat="button in buttons">
        <div ng-if="!button.isDisabled()">
          <a href="{{here}}" ng-click="button.onClick()">{{button.text}}</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-if=!button.isDisabled()">
          {{button.text}
        </div>
    </li>
```

You can do some nice styling to the disabled version to make it flow better. But, I would not use bootstrap `disabled` class here.